# Antenna as part of deformed circuit

Tags: capacitor, antenna, receiver

I have a basic question on my rudimental understanding on antennas. In [this
discussion](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/3502/are-antennas-circuits) or more precisely according to  [this answer](https://ham.stackexchange.com/a/3511) essentially an antenna can be regarded as a part of *deformed* LC circuit,
where the antenna itself is the deformed capacitor
(analogous philosophy for loop antenna: there the antenna is the deformed
induction coil, but let us focus on dipole or monopole antennas where
the rod is the the deformed capacitor). That is

[image]

Now I'm a bit confused about the first two partial circuits which should design
an embedding on an antenna in a receiver circuit I found [in this blog:](http://www.gsm-modem.de/M2M/m2m-faq/how-to-design-an-antenna-matching-circuit/)

To emphasise the problem let's draw the first two:

[image]

Now if we apply the intuitive interpretation of antennas as deformed capacitors
in a LC curcuit from the linked thread we obtain for 1 and 2:

[image]

But these are *not really* LC curcuits, at least the first one definitely
not, since there is nowhere a induction coil.

Why nevertheless this is a reasonable design of an antenna embedding? Or maybe,
in light of discussion in thread above, where my understanding on antennas
as deformed capacitors in LC curcuits fail regarding the 1 designed circuit
in the image above?

Comment: "This answer" explicitly says this: *antennas have capacitance and inductance.*

Answer (score 1):

As briefly mentioned in the answer you linked, the antenna also has inductance, so you can draw a coil or two in series with that capacitor. Any piece of wire has inductance; usually we consider it insignificant, but it does exist, and it will be enough to resonate with the antenna's capacitance at some frequency. If that's the frequency we're using the antenna at, then we call it a resonant antenna.

Comment: I understand, so if we want to model the antenna rod didacticaly correctly 
as a LC circuit which forms a part of a exterior circuit then we
have to replace better the rod by a capacitor plate AND inductance coil in 
series, then it will a model by a LC circuit.  
So the antenna is a LC circuit as itself, and not a *part* of a LC circuit
like a single capacitor would be, right?

Comment: On the other hand which role plays the capacity depicted in **circuit 1**? In **circuit 2**
the combination of depicted coil and 2 capacities seemingly form a frequency filter.
But what is then the role of single capacitor in circuit one? Is it only there to kill direct current?